# How to select an IP from an IP Range?

Tags: php, ip

My goal is to create a function that selects an IP Address from a give IP Range.

At the moment I am using this function:

```
function IPRange($start, $end) {
    $start = ip2long($start);
    $end = ip2long($end);

    return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end));
}
```

I know that this function only generates the IP Range, but how can I select an IP after that range is generated?

Example:
I have the given IP Range 93.118.193.0 - 93.118.193.255. From this range, automatically get one (for example: 93.118.193.83) and set it as "remote-address" attribute. If the IP is already set, get another one randomly (so that two "remote-address" are identical).

I tried to use `safelong2ip("127.0.0.1/32");`, but everytime it generates me the same IP: 0.0.0.93.

Comment: What does "select" mean?

Comment: @ChrisHass, by "select" I mean to take an IP from that range an set it as remote-address for my client attribute in CRM platform.

Comment: Can you edit the above with what you'd expect this function to take for inputs, and what you'd ideally get as an output?

Comment: If you just need to pick a random member from the resulting IP address array, use `array_rand($the_ip_arr)`, see:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = '10.3.63.2';
$end = '15.8.254.79';

var_dump(long2ip(random_int(ip2long($start), ip2long($end))));
```

`ip2long` gives you a simple number. Just generate a random number in a range, and turn that back into an IP with `long2ip`.

Comment: Thank you, I get a random IP everytime. Now, another thing that I want to do is to not create an instance with the same IP, how can I check in the IP Range for that IP so that the instance will not be created?